# Checkbox in RecyclerView index gets clicked twice

Tags: android, checkbox, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` list with `CheckBox` in the `CardView`, using a simple `onClickListener`. But when index `0` is clicked index `10` is also shown as clicked. The same if index `1` is clicked so is `11`, index `2` so is `12`, and so on. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Please share the code of onItemClickListener() and adapter's onBindViewHolder()

Comment: this question is cannot be answered in a reliable manner, unless providing the code, which produces the behavior... it is unclear what you are even asking. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the behavior of your `RecyclerView`. `RecyclerView` tries to recycle the views generated already with minimal changes in data. So in order to populate your data precisely in your list items, you need to tell exactly what it needs to show.

In your case, you need to keep the track of your checkbox click somewhere (maybe in a different array) so that you can populate the views accordingly. Let us consider the following code.

```
// Let us create an integer array having the same size of your list that is being passed to your RecyclerView
// Initially, all elements in the array is zero. 
private int[] array = new int[yourList.size()];
```

Now in your `onBindViewHolder`, I think you have implemented the `onClickListener` for your `CheckBox`. Hence when you are clicking the `CheckBox`, set the corresponding element in your `array` to `1`.

```
public void onClick(int position) {
    // Checbox click action here
    if (array[position] == 0) 
        array[position] = 1; // Use the position of your adapter to set the value.
    else array[position] = 0; // Toggle the values on check/uncheck
}
```

Now in the `onBindViewHolder` while populating the `CheckBox`, check the value of its position in the `array` and set the checked status accordingly.

```
if(array[position] == 1) checkBox.setChecked(true);
else checkBox.setChecked(false);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I used your code but I had to make some minor changes: first I hade to initialize the 'private int[] array = new int[yourList.size()];' to zero with a loop so that all the members of the array start at zero.

Comment: Ya, I just planted a pseudo code. I think you got the idea. So is it working now?

Comment: I used your code but I had to make some minor changes: first I hade to initialize the 'private int[] array = new int[yourList.size()];' to zero with a loop so that all the members of the array start at zero. Secondly, I had to add to the 'array[position] = 1;' the ability to go back to an unchecked view so: 'if(array[position] = 0 array[position] = 1 else if (array[position] = 1) array[position] = 0;' in the onClick listener.

Comment: You do not actually have to initialize the `array` with all zeros. If you don't perform any initialization, the array holds all zero elements in it automatically.

Comment: Yes, I agree with your second change. You need some kind of mechanism to toggle the values based on your check listener.

Comment: I have modified the answer accordingly. :)

Answer (score 0):

`RecyclerView` will reuse the layouts from previous rows when scrolling, so if you check item 1, and scroll, item 11 will still be checked unless told to not be.

Within your `onBindViewHolder`, you want to set the layout to the current state of the object you're displaying.

For example, say we have a list of `Dogs`, and we can mark if we've pet the `Dog`.

```
class Dog {
    public boolean hasPet = false;
    public String name;
}
```

Now, if you're displaying each `Dog`, you can do.

```
void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holde, int position) {
    Dog dog = list[position];
    holder.name = dog.name;

    // Remove any onCheckChangeListener or else we'll change the previously rendered dog.
    holder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

    // Set the checkbox to the current state of the dog.
    holder.check.setChecked(dog.hasPet);

    // Add a new onCheckChangeListener with the current dog.
    holder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            Logger.d("Clicked.");
            dog.hasPet = isChecked;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I didn't make myself clear, I need a code that works in Java.

Comment: Sorry, that should work now. It was mostly Java, but a few mistakes in Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

Three steps to solve it, and can be used everywhere you have a checkbox widget and it will be resued.

Firstly, Each adapter has a corresponding 'bean' binds to it. for example, List, The T is the bean.

Secondly, add a boolean field 'ischecked' into 'bean' class.

Finally, use this field to reset the status of checkbox when recycleview reuses checkbox, and update it when status of checkbox being changed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem because you didn't keep the click state for each item. You can modify your pojo and adding a check state property or you can simply using [SparseBooleanArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseBooleanArray) to hold the check state for all items.

Here the sample for using SparseBooleanArray.

Assuming we're using a simple pojo of User:

```
public class User {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    // constructor, setter, getter
}
```

**First**, create a SparseBooleanArray to hold the selected flags like this:

```
public class UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<User> mUsers;
    private SparseBooleanArray mSelectedFlags;

    public UserAdapter(List<User> users) {
        mUsers = users;
        mSelectedFlags = new SparseBooleanArray();
    }

    ...
}
```

**Second**, save the state whenever you click the CheckBox in your `ViewHolder`:

```
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView tvName;
        public TextView tvId;
        public CheckBox cbxSelect;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);

            ...
            // bind view here

        cbxSelect.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // set the state for specific item by its position.
                mSelectedFlags.put(getAdapterPosition()), isChecked);
            }

        });
    }
```

**Last**, set the state in `onBindViewHolder`:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ContactsAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

        int itemPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        User user = mUsers.get(itemPosition);

        viewHolder.tvId.setText(user.getId());
        viewHolder.tvName.setText(user.getName());

        // set the check state for each item
        // SparseBooleanArray will return false as default value
        viewHolder.cbxSelect.setChecked(mFlagSelected.get(itemPosition));

    }
```

---

The full adapter will be something like this:

```
public class UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<User> mUsers;
    private SparseBooleanArray mSelectedFlags;

    public UserAdapter(List<User> users) {
        mUsers = users;
        mSelectedFlags = new SparseBooleanArray();
    }

    @Override
    public UserAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        ...
        // inflate and return view holder.
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ContactsAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

        int itemPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        User user = mUsers.get(itemPosition);

        viewHolder.tvId.setText(user.getId());
        viewHolder.tvName.setText(user.getName());

        // set the check state for each item
        // SparseBooleanArray will return false as default value
        viewHolder.cbxSelect.setChecked(mFlagSelected.get(itemPosition));

    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView tvName;
        public TextView tvId;
        public CheckBox cbxSelect;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);

            ...
            // bind view here

        cbxSelect.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // set the state for specific item by its position.
                mSelectedFlags.put(getAdapterPosition()), isChecked);
            }

        });
    }
}
```